# Removing a row from a list from the adapter

Tags: android, listview, row

I am trying to implement a "favorite item" feature on my listview.
When user touches the "favorite" imageview of any row, if item was not a favorite, it becomes a favorite, and if item was a favorite, it becomes a non favorite AND the row disappears from the view. (There is a separate view in my app where user can set back the favorite to true if he wants to)

For each list item I am using Sharedpreferences to store if it is a favorite or not.

I am handling the clicklistener in my listadapter, not in my list activity.

Code of my ListAdapter:

```
public class ListItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItems> {

int resource;
String response;
Context context;

//Initialize adapter
public ListItemsAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ListItems> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
    this.resource=resource; 
}     

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LinearLayout ll;
    //Get the current alert object
    final ListItems i = getItem(position);

    //Inflate the view
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        ll = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater li;
        li = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
        li.inflate(resource, ll, true);
    }
    else
    {
        ll = (LinearLayout) convertView;
    }

// to display favorite icon on each row
    ImageView favo = (ImageView)ll.findViewById(R.id.favView);
    SharedPreferences sPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()); 
    if (sPrefs.getBoolean("fav"+i.id, false)==false) 
        favo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_favoriteno);
    if (sPrefs.getBoolean("fav"+i.id, false)==true) 
        favo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_favoriteyes);

// listener of the imageview to handle the user's touch
    final ImageView fav = (ImageView)ll.findViewById(R.id.favView);        
    fav.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            SharedPreferences sPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());     
            if (sPrefs.getBoolean("fav"+i.id, false)==false) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.addedToFavorite, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_favoriteyes);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPrefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("fav"+i.id, true);
                editor.commit();

                }

            else if (sPrefs.getBoolean("fav"+i.id, false)==true) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.removedFromFavorite, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_favoriteno);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPrefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("fav"+i.id, false);
                editor.commit();

                }
            }
        });


    return ll;
}
```

The display of the icon wether it is set as a favorite or not works well. What I don't manage to do is to make the row disappear as soon as the user sets the favorite icon as no.

I have tried to add notifyDataSetChanged(); in the onclicklistener but it does nothing.
It is possible that I don't get what I want because I am trying to do this in my ListAdapter class and not my Activity class.
The problem is that each row has several icons each with an onclicklistener, so I think I can't use the activity class to handle the click, but maybe I am wrong

Comment: I's okay to do all this in the adapter. Is the onClickListener called?

Comment: Yes I could verify it was called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you actually remove it from the data set of the adapter? 
Because I can't see the [remove](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#remove%28T%29) call to your ArrayAdapter in your code of the OnClickListener.

The adapter itself cares only about it's data set  - not how you paint the view (which is what you do with your favorites.

Comment: I guess you are right, because I don't use the remove method. What I don't manage to do is to call remove from the Adapter. How can I refer to the arrayadapter from inside the onclicklistener?

Comment: I guess you could use the Tag (setTag/getTag) field of the imageview to store this link back to the adapter. (The imageview you can access because it is passed to you in the listener)

Apart from that: You should also note that every time you need a new view (when scrolling this happens often!), you reconstruct a new Listener - this will slow down your scrolling and make it choppy. That's why you might want to consider the ViewHolder pattern for the actual list items here.

Comment: I totally agree this code needs improvements! When you mention tag, just to be sure, would that be INSTEAD of sharedprefs or ON THE TOP OF?

Comment: On TOP! Because a tag only lives as long as the View itself and you'd use your preferences to store it permanently.
(Otherwise, when scrolling, the view would be recycled and poof! - your 'favorite' state would be lost for the scrolled-out item)

Comment: Actually this answer here sounds like what you need to implement it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009983/deleting-an-item-from-listview-by-clicking-on-imageview-widget

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I think I am close to the solution thanks to your comments and the link. I might ask more questions later but in the meantine, i am checkmarking your answer. Thanks for your answers and your time!

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, just to remove a row from list view,

As you are assigning ListItems in ListItemsAdapter's constructor,

You just need to remove the item from ListItems, and reassign the adapter to listview or call notifyDataSetChanged for the adapter,code is as below,

```
items.remove(location);
adapter = new ListItemsAdapter(this,1, items);//not sure about integer parameter so I just put 1
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

or

```
items.remove(location);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

either of above two options should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just don't understand where I should put this code in the Adapter. Could you please indicate it?

Comment: @Kintaro  As you are creating a linearlayout for view and adding onclicklistener to fav, you can add this code inside onclicklistener, but I am not sure about it, will it work or not,
Another option is you create a custom layout for your listitem,
Inflate that layout in your getview, add onclicklistener in .xml layout itself, and write the onclicklistener in your activity,
In this onclicklistener I am sure that this code will work.